# Youtube Player API: get duration of advertisement

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Is it somehow possible to check (via player API) whether and ad is shown prior to the video and if so, how long it is or maybe when the ad is over? And also if the ad was skipped? The online API reference does not say anything about advertisements.

Comment: AFAIK there is no api to access advertisement data. When an ad is playing, the YouTube player object will report that it hasn't started yet (and may not even have a video duration yet, as the player generally waits to load video metadata when the ad is done).